# HDD is not opening

Tags: hard-drive

my HDD partition is not opening  (MOON is my HDD partition name)

ERROR

```
Error mounting /dev/sda4 at /media/praveen/MOON: Command-line `mount -t "ntfs" -o "uhelper=udisks2,nodev,nosuid,uid=1000,gid=1000,dmask=0077,fmask=0177" "/dev/sda4" "/media/praveen/MOON"' exited with non-zero exit status 14: The disk contains an unclean file system (0, 0).
Metadata kept in Windows cache, refused to mount.
Failed to mount '/dev/sda4': Operation not permitted
The NTFS partition is in an unsafe state. Please resume and shutdown
Windows fully (no hibernation or fast restarting), or mount the volume
read-only with the 'ro' mount option.
```

Answer (score 0):

Looks like your Windows session didn't finish properly. Try rebooting to Windows, shutting down the system in the ordinary way, than booting back to Linux and trying again.